# TypeScript and React: Pass 2 different arrays to a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using a prop **bodyData** that receives 2 differently typed arrays depending on which page I am on.

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like the 2 arrays are interconnected/conflicting. Thanks.

**The 2 different array interfaces**

**Listings interface**

```
export interface ListingsItems{
  id: number;
  img: string;
  itemNo: number;
  source: string;
  title: JSX.Element;
  sell: number;
  cost: number;
  profile: number;
  markup: JSX.Element;
  stock: JSX.Element;
  created: JSX.Element;
}


export const listingsData: ListingsItems[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: dataoneimg,
    itemNo: 1234546789,
    source: 'Amazon',
    title: (
      <div className="w-title align-items-center my-auto">
        {' '}
        <p className="mb-0">Title of the product</p>{' '}
      </div>
    ),
    sell: 30.4,
    cost: 34.44,
    profile: 309,
    markup: <div className="pl-2">30%</div>,
    stock: (
      <div className="pl-1">
        <i className="d-green far fa-check-circle"></i> 2
      </div>
    ),
    created: (
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
        13/07/2021 12:56
        <img className="ml-4" src={editicon} />
        <img className="ml-3" src={doticon} />
      </div>
    )
  },
]
```

**Order types**

```
export interface OrderItems{
  id: number;
  img: string;
  sale: string;
  qty: string;
  source: string;
  title: string;
  sold: string;
  cost: string;
  fees: string;
  profit: string;
  margin: string;
  orderOn: string;
  state: string
}

export const orderData: OrderItems[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: dataoneimg,
    sale: '-',
    source: 'Amazon',
    title: 'Title of the product',
    qty: '1',
    sold: '€15.99',
    cost: '€12.99',
    fees: '€1.00',
    profit: '€1.00',
    margin: '-',
    orderOn: '13/07/12:56',
    state: 'Error'
  },
]
```

**How I'm using them to define my `bodyData` prop**

```
interface props {
  bodyData: Array<ListingsItems | OrderItems>;
}
```

**How I'm using the bodyData prop in a component**

```
<ListingsTable bodyData={listingsData} headerData {listingsHeadingData} />
```

**The error that I'm getting when I try to map over the `bodyData`**

```
/home/moshe/upwork-gigs/hgrweb/src/components/tables/ContentTable.tsx
TypeScript error in /home/moshe/upwork-gigs/hgrweb/src/components/tables/ContentTable.tsx(72,66):
Property 'sale' does not exist on type 'ListingsItems | OrderItems'.
  Property 'sale' does not exist on type 'ListingsItems'.  TS2339

    70 |                   <img src={obj.img} alt="" />
    71 |                 </td>
  > 72 |                 <td className="obj-sale-body order-td-none">{obj.sale ? obj.sale : obj.itemNo}</td>
       |                                                                  ^
    73 |                 <td className="obj-sale-body order-td-none">{obj.source}</td>
    74 |                 <td className="obj-sale-title order-td-none">{obj.title}</td>
    75 |                 <td className="obj-sale-qty order-td-none">{obj.qty ? obj.qty : obj.sell}</td>
```

Comment: `<ListingsTable bodyData={listingsData} headerData {listingsHeadingData} />` is missing an `=` after `headerData`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListingsItems` *doesn't have a field `sale`.*  `OrderItems` does.

The error message pretty much says it all.

If you look at this [repl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGQQGcZkBzIgSVQFsiBvAKDkQBMAuOJAVxoCM0AbmaIaZTiSjlhLBLQByETj35CRRCNyi4JMKUjIy4RYABtTy3gKhHsEEpdU2RYKBHQJTwR9eEBfRkDQSFg4OyQSOFNiUgMiABFMGExOQhJyKloiAG0AXTgAXjhskSYWWQ44AEYAGhFZMU4AIia68sQFJWqAJgBmABYAVn6ANgB2AA4ATjbyjS0dOAByAEEaTAAvCCQl2ZYTc05egAYAOn69sPsYI-7zi-q4V3dPbzgTmZE-Otyg8Gh4MhUBgcHgAPJQVhoajAOhlNg%20NQNcTGPTSdSYLy6fSGEQARxgAE9sej9pptG9JKS4KQYFjUTijBpTJUqQZbNcSeyROhgMAiFzcSxnh4bgzqesoGRkIKjNAoVAwUhZepkqhBYwAoxggCrhF4PK0IlkpwIQqYXQ8oViqVHghKrU7Y04C1LkRMW8lgBaXaPeYUzirdZbHaXWn0pYAFTkXjg7hpAAs8M9WNxsDBfe0CcTllVM3MICzA4Aagiqg1OUym%20ZYdgcy1L3QrVcuvP5Jaqp2Ox2rTzcovbne7l0l0uVyx9l0NirHSyqvQA9McxvOqt12IMRj2SElPQBRKBuKBLL4-QJAtBYXC9iBgIhweF8CCsQnGlJwFYHzCEgA8aViFAtO8AB84DNaEsgAPn8QJ53nOBdxATAaGQchEzwKc4ygKIYlQ1gECgYB01MQlGHCSIp2Oa0p1fbJjlyYQKNOd0vECMj4GidIDEoooOP-BIkkwWj6MYXjyDOZjgBguCEKQlCDDgTA70wOAPDMVg43QF1nlvJoaUJMB0L4AArQiYFI7ZIm0ogqk4KzrQfJ8XwEzhqIEzVAisjtH2fGi6KYj1WIs%20ArO6eyRG8pyTWwziKFfdyQtOCLfNyfyWMCIA), you can see the errors that happen when you try to dereference the `sale` property on the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

It might make your code if you also define a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
const isOrderItems(item: ListingsItems|OrderItems): item is OrderItems => !!item.sale;
```

Then you can use that to have TS disambiguate the type in each branch:

```
 <td className="obj-sale-body order-td-none">{isOrderItems(obj) ? obj.sale : obj.itemNo}</td>
```